# Firefox Issue - dynamically created select element not working inside table

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, html-table, html-select

Browser - Firefox 51.0.1 (64-bit)
OS - Ubuntu 14.04

First I Created a table dynamically, The table has two columns which are editable. using an onclick event I created input/select elements dynamically by which the values were edited and saved.

One of the columns required a select input tag. using an onclick event on the table cell was able to add the element to the same.

```
function i_edit_avail(no, event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var table = document.getElementById('plot-binfo');
    var oCells = table.rows.item(no).cells;
    var val = oCells.item(6).innerHTML;
    var el = '<div style="position:relative"><select id="select-'+ no +'" onclick="prevent_bubble('+ no +', value, event)" onchange="i_select_avail('+ no +', value, event)">'+
              '<option value="Available" label="Available">Available</option>' +
              '<option value="Sold" label="Sold">Sold</option>'+
              '<option value="Unavailable" label="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>' +
              '<option value="Booked" label="Booked">Booked</option>'+
            '</select></div>';
    if(document.getElementById("select-"+no))
        console.log("can't add element");
    else {
        oCells.item(6).innerHTML = el;
    }
}
```

This newly created element works perfectly fine with chrome 56.0.2924.76 (64-bit).

The newly created element is unclickable(options don't show up) in Firefox. It does not trigger the events associated with the element.

Is there a workaround/fix for this issue. Or am I doing something wrong that is causing this problem.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Also, can you create a code snippet to show us?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/puyko02a/1/

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be the `contenteditable="true"` on the `td` tag. Removing it fixes the problem.

```js
function edit_val(v) {
  var table = document.getElementById('table-1');
  var oCells = table.rows.item(v).cells;
  var val = oCells.item(0).innerHTML;
  var el = '<select id="select-' + v + '" onclick="prevent_bubble(' + v + ', value, event)" onchange="i_select_avail(' + v + ', value, event)">' +
    '<option value="Available" label="Available">Available</option>' +
    '<option value="Sold" label="Sold">Sold</option>' +
    '<option value="Unavailable" label="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>' +
    '<option value="Booked" label="Booked">Booked</option>' +
    '</select>';
  if (document.getElementById("select-" + v))
    console.log("can't add element");
  else {
    oCells.item(0).innerHTML = el;
  }
}

function prevent_bubble(x, y, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = y;
}

function i_select_avail(a, b, event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = b;
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<table id="table-1">
  <tr>
    <th>Availability</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1">
    <td onclick="edit_val(1)">Available</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```